# Do troublemakers prevent single problem faceoffs?

Tags: my-little-pony-ccg

I've been poring over the Comprehensive Rules v.2 for MLP:CCG and I cannot find anything in the rules that implies that troublemakers prevent single problem faceoffs.  It's in the base rules, but the rules for troublemakers have changed significantly enough that I don't know the answer to this question.

If I confront only one problem, and the opponent could confront the same problem except that they are blocked by my troublemaker: do I simply score the problem, or is there a faceoff?

The FAQ for the comp rules says that "troublemakers only prevent confronting the problem not faceoffs", which seems to contradict the basic CN rulebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [comprehensive rules](http://enter-play.com/products/MLP_CCG_Comprehensive_Rules_v2.pdf), rule 611.4 says

> As a player confronts a Problem, that player scores a point. **If an opponent also meets their confront requirements for that Problem (611.3), there will be a Problem Faceoff at that Problem.**

And rule 611.3e says

> A player can’t confront a Problem if there is an opposing face-up Troublemaker or a face-up Troublemaker with Villain at that Problem.

611.4's reference back to 611.3 implies that there would be no faceoff (in accordance with the basic rules, whew), as the same confront requirements (611.3e) are needed unless there is a double problem faceoff.

Comment: Do you think you can edit this answer to more fully explain the rules interaction? If not, do you mind if I do it?

Comment: @murgatroid99  I can do it but I won't have time until tomorrow, so feel free to!  Thank you!